# Drop not working in drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html

fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/970/ here i want to drag my text which is .a,.b,.c,.d to droppable ans_set1_1.

```
 <div class="ans_set1_1" style="height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid black;"></div>



<div class="abcd">
    <div class="a" id="draggable"><b>(a)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="b" id="draggable"><b>(b)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="c" id="draggable"><b>(c)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="d" id="draggable"><b>(d)</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });
    $(".ans_set1_1").droppable({
        accept: ".a,.b,.c,.d",
                });
});
});
```

fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/970/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tby5k4jo/)

You will have to use revert:"invalid" attribute.

```
 $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
        revert:'invalid',
        start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
```

And the size of the draggable div's should be smaller than the droppable div, so that they fit in the droppable container.

```
<div class="ans_set1_1" style="height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
<div class="abcd">
<div class="a" id="draggable" style="width:25px;"><b>(a)</b>
</div>
<div class="b" id="draggable" style="width:25px;"><b>(b)</b>
</div>
<div class="c" id="draggable" style="width:25px;"><b>(c)</b>
</div>
<div class="d" id="draggable" style="width:25px;"><b>(d)</b>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NitishDhawan, which browser (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5DCZw/972/)

```
$(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({

        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });
```

revert: true will not allow you to change it's original position

```
// check for draggable
        if (//isnot that box) {
            $(this).data('rejected', true);
        }
```

Comment: if .a,.b,.c,.d is dropped in the box then ok else revert this is what i want

Comment: can u elaborate @ user3801433

Comment: what would be the condition //isnot that box

Answer (score 0):

Why not something basic like this:

```
  $(function() {
    $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable();
    $(".ans_set1_1,.ans_set1_2,.ans_set1_3,.ans_set1_4").droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: if .a,.b,.c,.d is dropped in the box then ok else revert this is what i want